# Angular nested route component, when to fire event for notifying subcomponent?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app with the following structure:

- Main component which renders several subcomponents in a
  `<router-outlet>`.
- Service which has a resource as `Subject<Resource>()` and `resource.asObservable()`.
- Several subcomponents which subscribe to the observable.

My main component fetches a resource from an API. The subcomponents are supposed to display a part of the resource each.

Main component fetches the resource in `ngOnInit`, after which it sets the resource in the service using `service.resource.next()`. The problem is that it does this before the subcomponents are loaded (apparently), because the callback function that i passed to the `subscribe` function in the subcomponents does not get called.

The subcomponents subscribe to the resource in the service in their constructor.

How do i ensure that the main component sets the resource at a time where the subcomponents are loaded and can receive the update from the observable? Is there a different function that i need to use apart from `ngOnInit`? Or is there a different way entirely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `Subject<Resource>()` you want `ReplaySubject<Resource>(1)`

replay subject will replay the last N emissions to new subscribers, where N is the argument to the constructor, so in this case, just the last 1.